# Add json data while classifying in angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json data as :

```
[{
    "name": "a",
    "data": "north",
    "value": "10",
    "finished": "50"
}, {
    "name": "b",
    "data": "north",
    "value": "100",
    "finished": "10"
}, {
    "name": "c",
    "data": "north",
    "value": "20",
    "finished": "50"
}, {
    "name": "a",
    "data": "south",
    "value": "80",
    "finished": "10"
}, {
    "name": "b",
    "data": "south",
    "value": "100",
    "finished": "10"
}, {
    "name": "c",
    "data": "south",
    "value": "30",
    "finished": "70"
}]
```

I want to add and classify the data according to name. For example : "name" :"a" will have value 10+80 =90,finished "50+10" =60, b will have value 200 and so on..

I am storing the json data in angular scope.

```
$scope.cuurentData = data;
var totalData = $scope.currentData;
for (var i = 0; i < totalData.length; i++) {
    if (totalData.name === "a") {
        // right code 
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to add the data and proceed further here.

Comment: Use javascript **reduce** function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.currentData=data;               
$scope.classifiedData=[];//This will hold the classified result

   $scope.currentData.forEach(function(elem1){
        var flag = false;
        var i = 0;
        $scope.classifiedData.forEach(function(elem2, index){                
            if(elem1.name == elem2.name){
                flag = true;
                i = index;
            }
        }); 
        if(flag){
            $scope.classifiedData[i].value = Number($scope.classifiedData[i].value)+Number(elem1.value);
            $scope.classifiedData[i].finished = Number($scope.classifiedData[i].finished)+Number(elem1.finished);
        }else{
            $scope.classifiedData.push(elem1);
        }   
      });
//Check the final result
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.classifiedData));
```

Comment: I want to add values only of same data property. If name == "a",  corresponding data value should be added.

Comment: that can be done(I will edit the code with the required one),but what about the value of data for example - for "a" its north and south,so which one you want in final array?

Comment: I want the sum of north and south  values. so it would be for example for 'a' : {"name": "a", "data":"north", "value": "10","finished": "50"}, +{"name": "a", "data": "south", "value": "80", "finished": "10"},   =>{"name": "a", "value": "90", "finished": "60"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript reduce function

```
result = data.reduce(function(b, a){
    var existing;
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        if(b[i].name == a.name) existing = b[i];
    }; 
    if (existing){
        existing.value = Number(existing.value) + Number(a.value);
        existing.finished = Number(existing.finished) + Number(a.finished);
    } else {
        b.push(a)
    }
    return b;
}, []);
```